# how a server could pass the digital certifcate to the client / browser

Tags: java, ssl, encryption

I have been writing a server using **Java** to receive client requests. It worked fine, but I have no idea how to implement SSL / https for the authentication module.

I have researched on the mechanisms, but when I try to use ajax request to request my server under https protocol, the request header(s) as well as the form-data are all **auto encrypted**.... I thought the client (browser in this case) should ask the server for the public-key for encryption instead. Now the server just received chunks of encrypted characters and have no idea what was happening.

so my question is how to implement the SSL authentication in the right way, at least how my server could pass the public-key to the client for encryption.

Comment: Well if you want to write your very own authentication module you will  have to implement the TLS/ SSL protocoll from scratch and follow it. Otherwise this part already happened when you receive "chunks of encrypted characters" (which you should be able to decrypt with your server sprivate key)

Comment: How is your server implemented? Are you running inside a container (such as `Jetty` or `Tomcat`), or are you using `SSLSockets` directly for communication? Once you've set up things correctly, the encryption is transparent to both sides.

Comment: well, I am not using any existing containers, just plain SSLSockets  and SSLServerSocket for direct communication. I execute the SSLSocket.startHandshake(), it seems no error, but the ajax request just returned "ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE". Again, the browser didn't warn for a certificate or any access to unsecured website... so I think something must have been left out in my implementation.... any ideas, guys?

Answer (score 0):

> I thought the client (browser in this case) should ask the server for the public-key for encryption instead.

No. SSL doesn't use public-key encryption.

> Now the server just received chunks of encrypted characters and have no idea what was happening.

You are receiving TLS.

> I thought the client (browser in this case) should ask the server for the public-key for encryption instead.

No. See above.

> so my question is how to implement the SSL authentication in the right way, at least how my server could pass the public-key to the client for encryption.

Your server doesn't have to pass the public key to the client for encryption, and in any case encryption and authentication are two different things. You are the victim of a misunderstanding. Just set up your keypair and certificate and use `javax.net.ssl.SSLSocket,` as described in the JSSE Reference Guide.

Comment: Ok, so now I changed to create a SSLSocketServer and changed the received socket into SSLSocket. But the ajax requests returned a status "ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE". And the browser didn't request for a certificate as well (usually a screen/warning should be asked if proceed to unsecure website etc)